# Proper way of measuring GPRS and 3G bandwidth

Tags: java, blackberry, upload, io, benchmarking

I need to measure real transfer rates in several GPRS and 3G BlackBerry devices. Since this data depends on the carrier and the device, and most online speed tests rely on JavaScript, Flash or HTML5, I felt the need to develop my own benchmarking app.

As I don't have any server to open a socket, but I can use several HTTP servers in my company, I'm using an `HTTPConnection` to get a file (HTTP GET) and to post a number of bytes (HTTP POST), then measuring the elapsed time. The download speed seems correct and is consistent with the known speed bounds I found in the internet, but the upload test is yielding totally unexpected results, several times greater than the download speed, and also greater than the theoretical upload speed limits. Tested on simulators and real devices as well. This is the code for the upload test:

```
    Httpconnectionection connection = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

    try {
        connection = getHttpconnectionection(url);
        if(connection != null){
            connection.setRequestMethod(Httpconnectionection.POST);

            os = connection.openOutputStream();
            for(int i = 0; i < numbytes; i++){
                os.write(0);                        
            }
            os.flush();

            int respCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (respCode != Httpconnectionection.HTTP_OK) {
                userMessage = "HTTP Response code: " + respCode + "\nMessage: " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }
        } else {
            userMessage = "unable to connnect";
        }                   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        userMessage = e.toString();
    } finally {
        if(os != null){
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }

        if(connection != null){
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Is this test correct if I were to execute a similar one on JavaSE or Android? Am I doing something wrong? I'm puzzled here.

My second question is more BlackBerry-specific: I know that in BlackBerry the MDS adds some compression. Could it be that both simulators and devices (all my devices are on BIS or BES) compress the sent data (which are all zeroes, so very good to be compressed) and in so doing the test does not count the real number of bytes sent but the compressed ones?

---

UPDATE: About my second question, I suspected the MDS might be compressing so I changed the write line for this one, to add enthropy to the test:

```
os.write(i);
```

I also updated the test harness to support different connection modes and test with TCP direct as  MrVincenzo suggested. these are the results:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   Connection Mode |   Mean Speed (3G) |   Mean Speed(GPRS)|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   BIS             |   390 Kbps        |   90 Kbps         |
|   Direct TCP      |   255 Kbps        |   17 Kbps         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

This proves that MDS compresses the data, and the series of zeroes I was sending at first was very likely undergoing high compression. Now the 17 Kbps for direct TCP under GPRS sounds a lot more reasonable to me.

Comment: I'd suggest to repeat the test with direct TCP connection if possible (add `deviceside=true` to the url that you pass to `Connector.open()` in `getHttpconnectionection()`) and see what happens. This way you will be able to determine whether MDS compresses the sent data or not.

Comment: @MrVincenzo Thanks, that was a good point. Updated my question. You might want to post your comment in a question instead.

Comment: did you mean like the speed we can see in dialog box while downloading content. like 50KB/Sec ??

Comment: well I search on the net and on Docs but could not find same, It might be possible some programatical way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I've never worked neither on JavaSE nor on Android but IMHO the concept of your upload test  seems correct and I would have done the same with one difference. I would have opened `SocketConnection` (to an HTTP server or to a dedicated server) instead of `HttpConnection`. The reason is based more on **gut feeling** then on real facts.
   If you decide to go with dedicated server, you should consider the *Amazon EC2 On-Demand Instances* that provides dedicated server(s) for hourly usage and very low pricing. I had used them in the past for stress and load tests.
2. As for the second question, I'd suggest to repeat the test with direct TCP connection if possible and see what happens. This way you will be able to determine whether MDS compresses the sent data or not.

Comment: Thanks again. as for the Socket, I also though on it at first, but this is a test app and I'm not setting up any extra server nor deploying a ServerSocket on it. That's why I'm "spamming" an already existing HTTP server XD.

Comment: You can "spam" the existing HTTP server with SocketConnection as well. You can prepare a predefined byte array that contains the desired HTTP request, headers and body (possibly headers only and randomly build the body) and send it over SocketConnection. Tough, I am not sure that it justifies the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code with direct TCP connection and add `deviceside=true` to the url i.e. passed by `Connector.open()`. This may be help you.